# NullPointer when trying to access a Java ArrayList<User> that is NOT null

Tags: java, javafx, arraylist, nullpointerexception

I have an ArrayList within my UserController that stores all my User instances.

I am able to use my setUserList to successfully set the ArrayList as I am able to loop through and print the users first name with currentUser.getFirstName()

I trigger my Login function from a JavaFX button and I receive a NullPointer exception when simply trying to print the size of ArrayList which previously had a size of 1 and printed the users first name.

*UserController:*

```
 public class UserController {
    public ArrayList<User> userList;  //should contain one user thomas but gives null pointer
    //static ArrayList<User> userList;  //this does not return a null pointer

    public void setUserList(ArrayList list){
        userList = list;
        for (User user : userList) {
            User currentUser = (User) user;
            String firstName = currentUser.getFirstName();
            System.out.println("Users in the UserController: " + firstName); //prints the user thomas
        }
    }

    public void login(){
        try {
            System.out.println(userList.size()); //null pointer
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }
}
```

*UserInterface containing login method*

```
    public class UserInterface extends Application {

    User loggedInUser;
    UserRepo userRepo = new UserRepo();
    UserController userController = new UserController();
    Connection conn;

    //login.fxml
    @FXML
    public TextField InputEmailAddress;  
    @FXML
    public TextField InputPassword;  

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {

        String connectionURL = "jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/gymManager";
        String userName = "root";
        String userPassword= "root";
        try {

            conn = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionURL, userName, userPassword);
            if(conn != null){
                System.out.println("Connected to the database");
                ArrayList<User> list = userRepo.read(conn);

                userController.setUserList(list); //here is where I set the ArrayList<Users> in the USerController

                Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("login.fxml"));

                Scene scene = new Scene(root);

                stage.setScene(scene);
                stage.show();
            }

        } catch(SQLException e){
            System.out.println("Exception:" + e.toString()); 
        }  

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    public void login(ActionEvent event) throws Exception{

        userController.login();

    }



}
```

*login.fxml*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import java.lang.String?>
<?import javafx.geometry.Insets?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TextField?>
<?import javafx.scene.image.Image?>
<?import javafx.scene.image.ImageView?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.Pane?>
<?import javafx.scene.text.Font?>

<Pane maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="720.0" prefWidth="1080.0" styleClass="main-pane" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="classmanager.UserInterface">
   <children>
      <Button fx:id="loginButton" layoutX="583.0" layoutY="451.0" onAction="#login"  mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="56.0" prefWidth="191.0" text="Log In">
         <font>
            <Font name="Montserrat Regular" size="13.0" />
         </font>
         <styleClass>
            <String fx:value="white-btn" />
            <String fx:value="bg-blue" />
            <String fx:value="rounded-btn" />
         </styleClass></Button>
      <Button layoutX="784.0" layoutY="451.0" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="56.0" prefWidth="158.0" text="I'm new here">
         <font>
            <Font name="Montserrat Regular" size="13.0" />
         </font>
         <styleClass>
            <String fx:value="outline-btn" />
            <String fx:value="rounded-btn" />
         </styleClass></Button>
      <Button layoutX="563.0" layoutY="514.0" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="38.0" prefWidth="231.0" styleClass="transparent-btn" text="I've forgotten my password">
         <font>
            <Font name="Montserrat Regular" size="13.0" />
         </font></Button>
      <Label layoutX="581.0" layoutY="273.0" prefHeight="18.0" prefWidth="411.0" text="Book classes and manage your membership details here" textFill="#9a9a9a">
         <font>
            <Font name="Montserrat Regular" size="14.0" />
         </font>
      </Label>
      <Label layoutX="577.0" layoutY="180.0" prefHeight="18.0" prefWidth="353.0" text="Welcome to the" textFill="#1a73b5">
         <font>
            <Font name="Montserrat Medium" size="30.0" />
         </font>
      </Label>
      <Label layoutX="577.0" layoutY="217.0" prefHeight="50.0" prefWidth="411.0" text="Village Hotel Gym" textFill="#1a73b5">
         <font>
            <Font name="Montserrat Medium" size="40.0" />
         </font>
      </Label>
      <ImageView fitHeight="730.0" fitWidth="544.0" layoutX="-25.0" layoutY="-4.0" pickOnBounds="true" preserveRatio="true">
         <image>
            <Image url="@../login-banner.jpg" />
         </image>
      </ImageView>
      <TextField fx:id="InputEmailAddress" layoutX="581.0" layoutY="325.0" prefHeight="50.0" prefWidth="386.0" promptText="Email address" styleClass="login-input">
         <opaqueInsets>
            <Insets left="20.0" />
         </opaqueInsets>
         <font>
            <Font name="Montserrat Regular" size="13.0" />
         </font>
      </TextField>
      <TextField fx:id="InputPassword" layoutX="581.0" layoutY="384.0" prefHeight="50.0" prefWidth="386.0" promptText="Password" styleClass="login-input">
         <opaqueInsets>
            <Insets left="20.0" />
         </opaqueInsets>
         <font>
            <Font name="Montserrat Regular" size="13.0" />
         </font>
      </TextField>
   </children>
</Pane>
```

I simply can't understand why one method (setUserList) in the UserController class will tell me that the ArrayList contains 1 user and the other (login) will return a NullPointer

Thanks for any tips

Comment: your ArrayList is not accesible in that function. you have to make it as static

Comment: Probably you call `setUserList` on one instance of `UserController` and then call `login` on another instance.  From your code it is unclear where `userController` value comes from and what instance of `UserController` method `login` is called on.

Comment: so one copy can be shared between the different functions

Comment: Agree with @MikhailVladimirov. Or you call ```login()``` for the same instance before ```setUserList``` call.

Comment: Hi thanks for getting back so quick. I've updated the question to show the full UserInterface class. From what I can see, both setUserList and login are both called on the same userController instance

Comment: Seems you have two ```UserController``` instances. One you create in ```UserInterface``` and set users list to it. Second one is created for login.fxml and is called on action. Could you provide your login.fxml?

Comment: The `read` method in `UserRepo` isn't included so we don't know what happens there. Personally I don't like having set methods for collection objects, I prefer to have something like `addUsers(List newUsers)` where I do `addAll(newUsers)` inside the method and then the list variable in the class is always initialized in the constructor

Comment: I've added the login.fxml file :)

Comment: @TomBudge see my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

Please change your User controller like this and see if it is working:

```
public class UserController {
public ArrayList<User> userList = new ArrayList<>();  //should contain one user thomas but gives null pointer
//static ArrayList<User> userList;  //this does not return a null pointer

public void setUserList(ArrayList list){
    userList.addAll(list);
    for (User user : userList) {
        User currentUser = (User) user;
        String firstName = currentUser.getFirstName();
        System.out.println("Users in the UserController: " + firstName); //prints the user thomas
    }
}

public void login(){
    try {
        System.out.println(userList.size()); //null pointer
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Hi thanks for your comment. Your fix removes the NullPointer, although the size of userList is still 0 when it should be 1. The list.size() = 1 inside the setUserList, but userLisr.size() = 0 in the login function

Comment: In your `UserInterface` is it possible `public void login(ActionEvent event) throws Exception` method to be call before `userController.setUserList(list);`?

Answer (score 0):

I bet that another instance of `UserInterface` created on fxml load, so you have another empty instance of `UserController` there. Use your `UserController` as controller for login.fxml.

1. Set `fx:controller` to `UserController` (classes are in the same package I guess).

```
<Pane maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="720.0" prefWidth="1080.0" styleClass="main-pane" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="classmanager.UserController">
```

2. Move TextFields declarations to `UserController`:

```
 public class UserController {
    public ArrayList<User> userList;  //should contain one user thomas but gives null pointer
    //static ArrayList<User> userList;  //this does not return a null pointer

    //login.fxml
    @FXML
    public TextField InputEmailAddress;  
    @FXML
    public TextField InputPassword;  

...
```

3. Do not instantiate `userController` in `UserInterface`:

```
    public class UserInterface extends Application {

    User loggedInUser;
    UserRepo userRepo = new UserRepo();
    UserController userController;
    Connection conn;
```

4. Change `UserInterface#start()`:

```
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {

        String connectionURL = "jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/gymManager";
        String userName = "root";
        String userPassword= "root";
        try {

            conn = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionURL, userName, userPassword);
            if(conn != null){
                System.out.println("Connected to the database");
                ArrayList<User> list = userRepo.read(conn);


                FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("login.fxml"));
                Parent root = loader.load();
                userController = loader.getController();

                userController.setUserList(list); 

                ...
```

5. Remove `login()` method from `UserInterface` and rewrite `login()` in `UserController` as follows:

```
@FXML
protected void login(ActionEvent event){
        try {
            System.out.println(userList.size()); //null pointer
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }
```